# Cant login to my wp-admin after switching to SSL

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I recently installed SSL certificate for my wordpress site(http to https) and now I'm unable to access Wordpress Admin. It refreshes the page and I am not logged in.

Is there something I forgot to change in my wordpress files?

I inspected the code and the login form is pointing to my old site (the http one) and when I look at the code in the file, the form action is set to site_url() and I can't seem to find where it's defined.

Comment: I have the same problem here. Do you fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change the site url in wp-admin->Settings->General. Except now you need to go in through phpMyAdmin and do it manually in the `wp_options` table since you are locked out.

You get different cookies depending on http/https so you are getting the https cookie and then being redirected to http that has no cookie because of your Wordpress settings that say what url the site resides at.

Comment: So I went into PhpMyAdmin and changed the site url in wp_options and cleared my cache and cookies and still was unable to login :(

Comment: there are 2 spots it wp_options to update. look for the other.

Comment: click "search" and with the `value` column search `http://%` with "LIKE" selected. If you get any results with your domain, change them to https.

Comment: If you intend on your entire site being https then i don't see why not.

Comment: I have changed all of those and I must say it fixed a few display issues I was having which is why I needed to login in the first place, but anyways after clearing my broswer and cache I am still unable to login.

Comment: Make sure cookies are enabled in your browser, make sure there isn't any confusion with www./no www., Verify you have the right credentials, and check your .htaccess file for anything referencing port 80 or http:// directly. I'm too blind to help you.

Comment: Would it be safe to post whats on my .htaccess file on here? this is what returns in my url `?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

Comment: that looks like a bad authentication. verify your password somehow.

Comment: When I enter in a wrong password I get an error `ERROR: The password you entered for the username admin is incorrect.` when I enter in the correct password I get redirected back to the sign in page.

Comment: This issue is fixed by going into `wp_login_redirects` in phpMyAdmin and changing http to https :)

Answer (score 34):

I had the exact same problem with my site on NearlyFreeSpeech.net, and the solution was not so simple as fixing the site URLs. That made no difference.

The underlying problem in my case, and the solution, were explained in the post copied below. Note that on my system, the SSL error created two problems, the one described here on Stack Overflow (wp-login refreshes without logging in) and a failure of WP to load stylesheets, which was the problem actually addressed in the forum post quoted below. The solution in the post solves *both* problems.

> What you describe sounds like the browser refusing to load the
>   stylesheet, which typically happens when first creating an
>   HTTPS-enabled WordPress site or adding SSL/TLS to an existing WP site.
>
> WordPress isn't very smart about "reverse proxies" like what NFSN
>   uses, where the user hits an outer web server that then talks to an
>   inner application server where WordPress actually lives.
>
> If you think you have an SSL-enabled site, especially if it's a new
>   one, this could be your problem. You would need to edit your
>   wp-config.php file to add the following:
>
> `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') 
>           $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';`
>
> just above the "That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging!" lines.
>
> Conversely, if you don't think you are using SSL on your site, this
>   won't do anything. Check the alias for your site on the NFSN site
>   control panel. If you see a padlock, you're set up in NFSN and need
>   the code above.
>
> WordPress's implementation of SSL is kind of a botch. It not only
>   doesn't recognize SSL under environments like ours - it also is prone
>   to redirect loops if everything isn't changed in exactly the right
>   order. If the code above causes a site outage - you keep getting
>   complaints from the browser about redirect loops - then remove the
>   code and ask again. I'll see if I can find my notes about how to do
>   initial SSL setup.

Comment: i have ```if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"]) && $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] == "https") $_SERVER["HTTPS"] = "on";``` still not able to fix.

Comment: Thanks, this did fix it for me

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to set the site URL manually in the wp-config.php file.

Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where "example.com" is the correct location of your site.

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
```

For more refer [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

or check in table `wp_options` column `option_name = siteurl` check the `option_value`

Comment: You saved me:)!

Comment: This helped me get into my wordpress site.  In my case I had gone into cloudflare and set SSL to "flexible" and in wordpress in Settings changed the site URLs to use https.  After that I got the too many redirects error and couldn't log in.  I was able to use the above fix except I used it to set my URLs to just "http".  I then logged into wordpress, went to settings, was able to remove the lines from the wp-config file, and reset the URLs to just http.  I then went into cloud flare and set SSL to Full mode.  Everything works now.  I feel lucky.

Answer (score 3):

I have used this first:

i have

```
if (
    isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"]) && 
    $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] == "https"
) {
    $_SERVER["HTTPS"] = "on";
}
```

still not able to fix and nothing happened.

Then I used

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
```

and I was able to connect to wp with https.

Now I have only minor issues of conflict (mixed https/http content on my page) but most things work.

Thank you!

Comment: I was able to resolve the mixed content issues, using one of the plugins available for this.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the cpanel>filemanager and edit the file wpconfig.php
inside php tags i added 
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with my wordpress instance.
Using ssh I went in to the directory structure and changed te wordpress root folder permissions to 755 and the .htaccess file to 644.

> chmod 755 wordpress/

After that I cloud access my admin panel again.

Answer (score -3):

Go to phpadmin and find wp-options. Change siteurl and home to http. Its work :)