# http to https – can't access wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, cpanel, wp-admin

I have a big problem and hope you guys can help me.

Recently, I went on WordPress, go to general setting and change my WordPress address and site address URL from http to https. I did not have any SSL. When I clicked save and reload the site, it gave me a "The requested URL /wp-admin was not found on this server."

https://bebelle.org/wp-admin

Is it possible to revert back to just http?
How can I fix it?

Thank you

I have tried many option.

1. Went on phpMyAdmin and change the siteurl and home to https and http and still give me the same problem.
2. Went into cpanel, under wp-config.hp and define my WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL, still give me the same problem.
3. I am running out of option.

Comment: Have a quick look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238288/cant-login-to-my-wp-admin-after-switching-to-ssl

Comment: I tried everything there still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Sir,go to cpanel and make reload to a previouse date when you hadn't yet make the change

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have changed url to https:// without SSL. The settings page was redirected and ewerithing was broken. I have spend more then 3 hours to resolve it. Now I do not remember exactly what I did, but it was like:

1. Go to wp-login.php, make a copy for backup
   1.1 Delete this all

> if ( force_ssl_admin() && ! is_ssl() ) {  if ( 0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http') ) {      wp_redirect( set_url_scheme( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'https' ) );      exit();     } else {        wp_redirect( 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );        exit();     } }

1.2 Delete this all:

> setcookie( $rp_cookie, $value, 0, $rp_path, COOKIE_DOMAIN, is_ssl(), true );

1.3 Delete this too:

> if ( ! $user || is_wp_error( $user ) ) {        setcookie( $rp_cookie, ' ', time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS, $rp_path, COOKIE_DOMAIN, is_ssl(), true );        if ( $user && $user->get_error_code() === 'expired_key' )           wp_redirect( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=lostpassword&error=expiredkey' ) );         else            wp_redirect( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=lostpassword&error=invalidkey' ) );         exit;   }

1.4 And this:

> ```
>   setcookie( $rp_cookie, ' ', time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS, $rp_path, COOKIE_DOMAIN, is_ssl(), true );
> ```

1.5 Delete this:

> if ( !empty($_POST['log']) && !force_ssl_admin() ) {        $user_name = sanitize_user($_POST['log']);      $user = get_user_by( 'login', $user_name );         if ( ! $user && strpos( $user_name, '@' ) ) {           $user = get_user_by( 'email', $user_name );         }       if ( $user ) {          if ( get_user_option('use_ssl', $user->ID) ) {              $secure_cookie = true;              force_ssl_admin(true);          }       }   }

1.6 Then delete this:

> $redirect_to = preg_replace('|^http://|', 'https://', $redirect_to);

2. Then you can go to http://url.com/wp-login.php and login. go to settings in admin panel and change back urls.
3. put backup with wp-login.php to return to stable version.
4. Delete cookies

I could make a mistake, but i did something like this and it helped me to resolve problem. The idea anyway is get to admin panel to chenge back urs from https:// to http://