# I have a problem with accesing wp-admin after forcing SSL

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, terminal

I just created a wordpress site with Vultr. I forced SSL on this domain but I can't acces my wp-admin section anymore. I need help! Thanks a lot

Comment: did you try https://yoursite.com/wp-admin ?

Comment: I think this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238288/cant-login-to-my-wp-admin-after-switching-to-ssl

Answer (score 0):

You need to change manually the site url to wp_options table in your database.

Comment: Thanks! How do I acces this trough my terminal in MACOS?

Comment: How did you force SSL? If you have the certificate installed you could consider a plugin called Really simple SSL to handle this properly.

Comment: Or check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238288/cant-login-to-my-wp-admin-after-switching-to-ssl?rq=1