# Can't login to wp-admin after switching to SSL

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https, http-status-code-400

I recently installed SSL certificate for organization's intranet wordpress site(http to https) and now I'm unable to access Wordpress Admin. 
It gave me this error:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2022 02:41:55 GMT Server:
> Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.0.3 Content-Length: 226
> Connection: close Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 Bad
> Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not
> understand.

I've tried every solutions from
[Cant login to my wp-admin after switching to SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238288/cant-login-to-my-wp-admin-after-switching-to-ssl)
but none is working.
Is there anything I'm missing. By the way, we are using F5 to implement the SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the DB and checking the wp_options table to see what the site URL is. Change it to HTTPS and try?

Comment: Did try that, but unfortunately the problem still remains.